# EndInvoke in Asynchronous web services returns useless value

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a problem with a simple C# web service from a sample. 
This is my server side code:

```
public delegate string LengthyProcedureAsyncStub(int milliseconds);

    public class MyState
    {
        public string text;
        public object previousState;
        public LengthyProcedureAsyncStub asyncStub;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public IAsyncResult BeginLengthyProcedure(int milliseconds, AsyncCallback cb, object s)
    {
        LengthyProcedureAsyncStub stub = new LengthyProcedureAsyncStub(LengthyProcedure);
        MyState ms = new MyState();
        ms.previousState = s;
        ms.asyncStub = stub;
        return stub.BeginInvoke(milliseconds, cb, ms);
    }

    public string LengthyProcedure(int milliseconds)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        return "Success";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string EndLengthyProcedure(IAsyncResult call)
    {
        MyState ms = (MyState)call.AsyncState;
        string result = ms.asyncStub.EndInvoke(call);
        return result;//ms.text;
    }
```

I consume the service from a client like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Waiter(5000);

    }

    private void Waiter(int milliseconds)
    {
        asyncProcessor.Service1SoapClient sendReference;
        sendReference = new asyncProcessor.Service1SoapClient();
        sendReference.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        sendReference.BeginLengthyProcedure(milliseconds, ServiceCallBack, null);

    }

    private void ServiceCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string strResult = result.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is that the client variable strResult should have "Sucess" as it's value, instead it has this: "System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel+SendAsyncResult". 
What am I doing wrong or overlooking?

Thanks in advance fro your time :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags stand alone.  Combining individual tags does not give them an additional meaning.  For example, combining `web` and `service` does not mean you're speaking about web services.

Comment: @Charles 
Thank you for the clarification Charles. I'll keep it mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `sendReference` instead of `null`.

```
private void Waiter(int milliseconds)
{
    asyncProcessor.Service1SoapClient sendReference;
    sendReference = new asyncProcessor.Service1SoapClient();
    sendReference.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    sendReference.BeginLengthyProcedure(milliseconds, ServiceCallBack, sendReference);

}

private void ServiceCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    asyncProcessor.Service1SoapClient sendReference = result.AsyncState as asyncProcessor.Service1SoapClient;
    string strResult = sendReference.EndLengthyProcedure(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Grzegorz. That solved the issue. I had another small detail after making the change. I was getting the error:
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'" that can be solved in IIS by enabling Annonymous access but it's against our policy so I changed another binding in app.config to use TransportCredentialOnly and worked great. Thanks again.